# Please identify my African violet

Tags: african-violets

[image]

Five petals color is fushia and white

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Might be Saintpaulia Optimara rhapsodie anika, but there are hundreds of varieties of these plants. Image here http://www.grow-african-violets.com/african-violets-varieties/optimara-rhapsodie-anika.html